# sampling from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I have a covariance matrix representing a multivariate normal distribution. I would like to draw samples from this distribution, e.g. using R's `mvrnorm`.

What happens if I diagonalize the covariance matrix in advance? This would yield a diagonal matrix, with the corrected variances on the diagonal.
Can I now sample from each gaussian independently? if so, what is the new mean?

Comment: If you replace the initial covariance with a diagonal one, this modifies the distribution you are sampling from.

Comment: My space is very sparse because this is a very high-dimensional Gaussian. Hence, few samples don't represent the initial distribution well. Is there a way to improve the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the formula $\text{Cov}(CX) = C \,\text{Cov}(X) \, C^T$ for how to compute the covariance matrix of a linear transform of a vector $X$, described by the matrix $C$. This shows that your method is indeed correct, however you need to linearly transform your independent Gaussians (put into a vector) to get samples from the original, correlated Gaussian vector. The mean will transform linearly; so in particular, if the original mean vector is zero, so is the one of the transformed vector.

The technique of principal components analysis is based on choosing not
only a diagonalising $C$, but also on putting the eigenvectors (principal
components in statistical language) belonging to the largest eigenvalues
first. It may be best to use a routine in R that computes only the
first few eigenvectors / principal components.